# HELP! I accidentaly moved many folders from root directories!

Tags: command-line, directory

So, I was in a folder where I maintain many other folders and subfolders. I accidentally run the command:

```
find /*/* -prune -type d -exec mv -t /home/myname/Music/Jazz/test {} +
```

obviously without knowing what I was doing. Now I see hundreds of folders coming from root directories in the target directory. I assume I moved folders from `/lib`, `/proc` and others. I'm afraid to restart the pc. Is there any way to reverse what I did?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to reverse what you did, unless you happen to have saved the output to a file

Comment: I do a search for random folders that seem moved and I see them in their original directories with same contents. Can it be the case that the command simply copied them because I didn't run it as sudo? Or do they show up because I'm still logged in and after a restart they will be removed?

Comment: Please run `ls -al /home/myname/Music/Jazz/test` and add to question lets see what was moved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't mess with permissions before, there should not be many directories in `/*/*` that a nonprivileged user may move. I suppose that you moved only your own /proc/* directories, perhaps /var/tmp or /tmp, too.

/lib, /opt and other directories cannot be moved with your userID.

Answer (score 0):

I was not in a root shell so it seems that all folders remained in their original places as well. A kind of copy operation then and after deleting the moved folders and restarted all were fine. We mark this as solved.